# keyring error when importing: module 'io' has no attribute 'text_encoding'

Tags: io, python-keyring

When importing keyring,

```
import keyring
```

for some reason I keep on getting error message: "AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute 'text_encoding' "
the line preceding the error refers to one of the site packages (py310compat.py on the zipp folder (File "C:\Users*user_name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\zipp\py310compat.py
io.text_encoding if sys.version_info > (3, 10) else _text_encoding  # type: ignore "

I've checked the py310compat.py on my Zipp folder, everything seems to be in place, unless my io library is on an outdated version ? (for some reason can't even find the io library folder on my local machine site packages sub folders, or seeing its version:

```
print(io.__version__)
```

will render: "AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute '**version**' "
although:

```
import io
```

runs with no issues, so I guess it has something to do with the way my io was installed

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when trying to backport the zipfile module from a newer version of Python.

The `io` module is a Python standard library module, so it's part of Python itself (it won't be in site-packages). The problem is that the `io.test_encoding` was added in Python 3.10 [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.text_encoding).